# Yii on amazon beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, yii

I know it's a long shot but i'll try anyway, 
I'm trying to setup a Yii app (php) on amazon elastic beanstalk.

All i did was upload the zip file with my app and wanted to see if it works but the response from the server is:
"Status Code:503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity"

I read around and it seems to be something with the load balancer, any ideas?

Comment: Does it work with just a single instance setup to confirm or eliminate the load balancer as the problem?

Comment: are you still having the problem? I successfully managed to run several yii apps on elastic beanstalk.